# scala/spark script from CLI

Tags: bigdata, sqoop

I am running `scala_script.scala` from unix cli and getting error of: `enycription key missing`, while the same scala code runs fine in spark-shell.

The code is used to access a hive table load it in dataframe, process some transformation and then again: `write.mode("append/overwrite").saveAsTable("my_db.my_table")`. Code is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val tb_applicant_details=hc.sql("SELECT * FROM staging_mps_25.applicant_details")
tb_applicant_details.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("spark_tests.new_test_person")
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to use spark-shell's :load "path_to_script".
another is to give correct drivers --driver and set --master yarn in spark-shell -i command, for runing script.
Like,
spark-shell -i --master yarn --driver"com.correct.driver" complete/absolute/path/to/script.scala